# Does having required input fields in your app result in your app being rejected from aproval from both Google Play and App Store?

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store

I know, it's silly, but a client was telling us that having required input fields on an app will result in the app being **rejected for approval on both Android and iOS** app stores.

Besides the fact that there are tons of apps that require user account registration and stuff, I figured it'd be silly to even verify it by research but of course, to be sure, I did research about it, but as I expected, I was not able to find even one relevant result.

Since it will cause problems with app development, I decided to ask here to confirm.

Does anybody know of such rule when submitting apps to the Google Play Store or App Store?

I apologize in advance for what I know is a very silly question, but I humbly ask for confirmation.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I have an app in Google Play Store with required fields. No such issues. Not sure about iOS though.

Comment: @Abhimanyu Thank you very much for the confirmation! I mean, it was obvious, but I just had to make sure. I'll wait for more confirmations on both Android and iOS.

Comment: You should acquaint yourself with the [data collection](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#data-collection-and-storage) guidelines from Apple. Generally if your app requires people to provide personal information including date of birth, address etc then you can expect to be rejected. If your app requires people to create an account/supply an email address and it doesn't include "significant account based functionality" then you can expect a rejection from Apple. However, as with all AppStore policy questions, only Apple/Google can answer and so this is off topic

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you very much for the indication! I'm not an iOS developer so I really don't encounter these data often, so your warning has been extremely helpful. Thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about an application store's policy, which is not on-topic for Stack Overflow.  See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

No, in Android we don't have this rule, so you can use input fields in your application without worrying.

Comment: Thank you very much for the confirmation!

Comment: You are welcome. Feel free to ask more questions :)